# Intent=browse is ignored for venues search in the area

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm trying to search tips in the area (using "**sw**" and "**ne**" parameters) and skipping "**ll**" parameter as it is not required in "**intent=browse**" mode
according to [doc](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search).

Getting error:

```
c({"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"Must provide ll parameter."},"response":{}});
```

Request URL is:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/search?intent=browse&sw=56.8284375%2C60.613698&ne=56.8301645%2C60.615842&client_id=XXX&client_secret=YYY&v=20120412&callback=c

PS. client_id and client_secret are specified correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, [tips search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/tips/search) method is **deprecated** and does not support **sw** and **ne** parameters. [Search for venues](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) is recommended for usage instead.